# Adding new columns from one another column with a third filtered column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 Columns (apologize about the names in advance!) "Historical Case Status Raw", and "Historical Status Start Date":

Historical Case Status Raw: Contains three statuses for a given case
Historical Status Start Date: Contains the Date for that status for a given case

I would like to take the each status and filter by it, then take the corresponding date and add it to a new column. I can perform this once, however when I try to do it for another status it only works for the new column and the previous column fails.

```
def closed_cases():
    df_copy = df.copy()
    df['Date Closed'] = np.nan
    df_copy.loc[df['Historical Case Status Raw'] == "Closed", 'Date Closed'] = df['Historical Status Start Date']
    return df_copy
```

I am unsure how to do the same for the status of "Enrolled", then make a new column called "Date Enrolled", and "New".

In Excel I perform 3 V-lookups to do this with three separate sets of data, however there is a combined set of data in this format I am hoping to use to save time.

Edit: I have found something that works albeit slow:

```
df['Date Closed'] = np.nan
df['Date Enrolled'] = np.nan
df['Date New'] = np.nan

for i in df['Historical Case Status Raw']:
    if i == "Closed":
        df.loc[df['Historical Case Status Raw'] == "Closed", 'Date Closed'] = df['Historical Status Start Date']
    elif i == "Enrolled":
        df.loc[df['Historical Case Status Raw'] == "Enrolled", 'Date Enrolled'] = df['Historical Status Start Date']
    elif i == "New":
        df.loc[df['Historical Case Status Raw'] == "New", 'Date New'] = df['Historical Status Start Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something faster, you need to better leverage pandas' slicing capabilities.
You rarely (if ever) need to loop over every value in a Series if you use it correctly.
I don't have data to test, but maybe try something that would look like this:

```
df['Date Closed'] = np.nan
df['Date Enrolled'] = np.nan
df['Date New'] = np.nan
universe = ['Closed', 'Enrolled', 'New']

for status in universe:
    selection = df['Historical Case Status Raw'] == status
    mySlice = df['Historical Case Status Raw'].loc[selection]
    df[f"Date {status}"].loc[selection] = mySlice
```

Note: in your loop it looks like you're assigning the entire series to a slice of a series from the same dataframe everytime you're in one the the if blocks. Again, without looking at your dataset I can't be sure but that looks like a red flag to me.

Anyways, those are my two cents. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I would have to make up a data set since there's PHI, but this puts me on the right track! It was MUCH faster :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped! Would you post the answer as an edit? I'm curious to know :P